# Dynamically created static text boxes: Getting and Handling STN_CLICKED messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, macros, mfc, message

MFC C++ project under MS VS2015. My plan is to dynamically create lots of (say >200) **CStatic** boxes using the extended styles: **WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE** to make them look nice. It means I can’t use **CStatic::Create**, instead using:

```
DWORD style = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_CENTER | SS_NOTIFY;

p->box = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "STATIC", nStr, style,
         p->posX, p->posY, p->sizeX, p->sizeY, this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), NULL );
```

It would be very convenient to find out if one of the static windows has been clicked so I set the **SS_NOTIFY** style. According to the docs I should get an **STN_CLICKED** notification, which is great. But this apparently goes through the **WM_COMMAND** message.

**WM_COMMAND** is not listed as an available message in the parent dialog properties.

If I manually create a static box in the parent dialog, and set the **Notify** property as true, I can get an **STN_CLICKED** handler which neatly goes in to the message map macro:

```
ON_STN_CLICKED( IDC_TEST, &CFamilyDlg::OnStnClickedTest )
```

Since I am dynamically creating the boxes, I can’t put one handler in for each static window. (In any case the **CreateWindowEx** function generates an **HWND** rather than having a control ID.)

I want to receive all **STN_CLICKED** messages, then use the **HWND** to tell me which one is active so I can do something about it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Would look at something like `ON_CONTROL_RANGE(STN_CLICKED, STID_MIN, STID_MAX, &YourFunc);` Google for ON_CONTROL_RANGE(). If that doesnt work, try ON_NOTIFY_RANGE

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, that works nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Joseph Willcoxson’s comment, I have added IDs to the dynamically created static boxes. (Just some random range for now)

```
DWORD style = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_CENTER | SS_NOTIFY;
p->box = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "STATIC", nStr, style, p->posX, p->posY, p->sizeX, p->sizeY,
             this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), NULL );

CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(p->box);
pWnd->SetDlgCtrlID( 0x1000 + idx);
```

Then a handler function:

```
afx_msg void OnPersonClicked( UINT nID );
```

And the suggested message map entry:

```
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(STN_CLICKED, 0x1000, 0x2000, OnPersonClicked )
```

***which now works as required*** :-)

The only difference for the real code is to add a couple of constants:

const int MIN_ID = 0x1000;
const int MAX_ID = 0x2000;

I didn't use an ampersand in front of the function name, but it works with or without it.

Comment: Please move the answer from the question here. This helps visitors quickly find answers.

Comment: Done, as requested.